# Privacy concerns

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I have a Stack Overflow profile which I publicize among my friends / potential employers etc. But I would not like people to see or know what questions or answers I post on sites like The Workplace. It is very easy to know the real life references from my post if a person knows me.

I wanted to express my concern about all of my questions being visible to any one who knows my Stack Exchange username. I am actually restraining my self from posting some questions pertaining to my workplace as many of my colleagues are active on Stack Overflow and they can easily know the context.

If there is a way I can hide my questions which I am not aware of, I apologize for posting this.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, but the short form is: you can't unlink an already-linked account, but you can create a new account with a different OpenID, and as long as you're careful not to let them mingle you'll be fine.  (E.g. don't use that new OpenID on any other SE site.)

Comment: see also: [Why separate Stack Exchange accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69422/why-separate-stack-exchange-accounts) at MSE